# Only display records that have incremented from a certain time frame

Tags: sql, sqlplus

In my database there is a table, ITEM_POWER, it includes ID #, READ_TIME, and POWER_COUNT.

Every time the item powers down, it increments POWER_COUNT + 1 in the table. An item could have 0 POWER_COUNT if it's never turned off, or it could have 1000 POWER_COUNT if it's turned off 1000 times.

I'd like to display items that have their POWER_COUNT incremented by 1 for a certain time frame, compared to the POWER_COUNT from a recent time frame.

Currently my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT ID, READ_TIME, POWER_COUNT
FROM ITEM_POWER WHERE READ_TIME BETWEEN '31-MAR-19' and '05-APR-19' 
AND POWER_COUNT > POWER_COUNT BETWEEN READ_TIME OF '24-MAR-19' AND '29-MAR-19'
GROUP BY ID, READ_TIME, POWER_COUNT
ORDER BY ID, READ_TIME, POWER_COUNT
```

Obviously I don't believe my line "AND POWER_COUNT > POWER_COUNT BETWEEN READ_TIME OF '24-MAR-19' AND '29-MAR-19' will work, that's just what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to compare the power_counts of this week, compared to last week, and if the power_count has incremented, I want to display the READ_TIME, and the new POWER_COUNT.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
ID READ_TIME POWER_COUNT
------------ --------- -----------
1234567 09-MAR-19         121
1234567 10-MAR-19         121
1234567 11-MAR-19         121
1234567 12-MAR-19         121
1234567 13-MAR-19         123
1234567 14-MAR-19         130
```

In the above data, ID 1234567 had it's POWER_COUNT incremented from 121 to 123 on '13-MAR-19'. For this example let's say I'd like to compare the POWER_COUNT between '13-MAR-19' and '14-MAR-19' to the POWER_COUNT at '12-MAR-19'. Since the POWER_COUNT has incremented since then, I'd like that ID displayed in my report. If the POWER_COUNT has not incremented from the previous date's value, I would like to exclude it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I've included some sample data, thanks for the recommendation! Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you just want `lag()`:

```
SELECT ID, READ_TIME, POWER_COUNT
FROM (SELECT IP.*,
             LAG(POWER_COUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY READ_TIME) as PREV_POWER_COUNT
      FROM ITEM_POWER IP
     ) IP
WHERE READ_TIME >= DATE '2019-03-21' AND
      READ_TIME < '2019-04-06' AND
      POWER_COUNT <> PREV_POWER_COUNT 
ORDER BY ID, READ_TIME, POWER_COUNT;
```